# Hosting hyperledger VM on ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine, hyperledger

When setting up the environment for hyperledger on windows using vagrant and docker, we create a VirtualMachine running ubuntu.
If I need to deploy my blockchain on another pc running ubuntu, will cloning the hyperledger VM and running the clone in a VirtualBox on ubuntu have the same effect?
(I am new to docker and virtual machine so dont have any idea about it. Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using vagrant no real need to clone your VM to another machine, it will be enough to just run vagrant on it. And basically yes, you should be able to clone and work on another pc.

Moreover if you'd like to have Hyperledger installed on bare linux machine, there is very useful [script](https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment) which you can use to provision hyperledger peer and orderers on specified IPs.